# spacemacs, evil insert-mode jump to the beginning of the line

Tags: spacemacs

I try to jump to the beginning/end of the line, and when I am in vim, I write the following code:

```
inoremap  <leader>a <Home>
inoremap  <leader>e <End>
```

and it works fine. However, when I am in spacemacs, I do this:

```
 (define-key evil-insert-state-map ",a" 'beginning-of-line)
 (define-key evil-insert-state-map ",e" 'end-of-line)
```

everything goes right except that I can't type comma anymore (I mean, when I type "," it just waits there). Here is the message when I type comma:

> a -> beginning-of-line e -> end-of-line

PS. I am working on Ubuntu 18.02 LTS with GNU Emacs 25.2.2
(I am new to spacemacs and know little about elisp)

Answer (score 1):

It seems this works fine:

```
 (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-a") 'beginning-of-line)
 (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-e") 'end-of-line)
 (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-n") 'next-line)
 (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-p") 'previous-line)
```